# Json children properties to dictionary

Tags: c#, json, linq

I'm trying to extract a list of dates for a property of all children nodes on a JToken but cannot get the syntax correct.

I want to get a list of dates in property `"timeStamp": "2013-09-11T00:30:00Z"` so I can determine the min/max dates for all child nodes.

I've tried the following which returns an anonymous type and makes it difficult to use the returned object.

```
var timeStamps = Jarr.Select(x => new
{
   timeStamp = (DateTime)x.SelectToken("timeStamp")
});
```

1. How can I get say a `List<string>` or `List<DateTime>` only of all child timestamps?
2. Is it possible to get a `Dictionary<string, DateTime>` of id, timestamp?

The Json looks like this, so essentially from LEVEL1 I want to check all children, children of children for the same property.

```
{
  "children": [
    {
      "type": "LEVEL2",
      "name": "Item1",
      "id": "1.7193",
      "timeStamp": "2013-09-11T00:30:00Z",
    },
    {
      "type": "LEVEL2",
      "name": "Item2",
      "id": "1.7194",
      "timeStamp": "2013-09-11T00:30:00Z",
    },
    {
      "type": "LEVEL2",
      "name": "Item3",
      "id": "1.7191",
      "timeStamp": "2013-09-11T00:30:00Z",
    }
  ],
  "type": "LEVEL1",
  "name": "Stock-FRT54443",
  "id": "1000145",
  "countryCode": "en"
}
```

and method

```
    void AddNodes(TreeView treeView, JObject jObj, TreeNodeCollection parent)
    {
        JToken Jarr = null;
        Dictionary<string, string> marketProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var property in jObj.Properties())
        {
            if (property.Name == "children")
            {
                Jarr = property.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                string key = property.Name;
                string prop = property.Value.ToString();
                marketProperties.Add(key, prop);
            }

        }

        if (marketProperties["type"] == "LEVEL1")
        {
          //Not working!
          var timeStamps = Jarr["timeStamp"].Values<string>();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the 'new' keyword it's going to create an anonymous type.  You're creating a list of objects with a timestamp property rather than a list of DateTimes.  All you need to do to get your date list is to change it to:

```
DateTime timeStamps = Jarr.Select(x => (DateTime)x.SelectToken("timeStamp")).ToList();
```

It's also possible to get a dictionary:

```
Dict<string,DateTime> dictionary = Jarr["children"].ToDictionary(x=>x["Id"].ToString(),x=>(DateTime)(x["timeStamp"]));
```

The second is untested but should give you the general idea.